# create variable can get accessed trough the request in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a case that a variable needs to be accessed trough the request, the flow goes like thist

1. custom Filter (retrieve request, doing stuff, set XXX variable)
2. controller (access XXX Variable)
3. custom lib (access XXX Variable)
4. repo (access XXX Variable)

i've read about requestcontext but i heard it'll become a problem when it comes to multithread, so what can you guys recommend to me ?

Thanks

Comment: you can put it in a cache via redis or caffeine. and it will be expired after some time to save space of memory.

Comment: okay, but how to associate that value in redis belong to this specific request or user ? is it posible mapping using timestamp or any other suggest ?

Comment: redis has more data type such as string, set, hash, list, sorted set, bitmap. etc. pls ref its doc to choose one according to your requirement. for example, use list to save each user   request. the key is userid. the latest value is in head of list.